# How to set size of Jtable in tab of JtabbedPane and how to set the layout of tabs in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jtabbedpane

I'm trying to make my first swing application and there's a problem which I can not figure it out. I want the `JTabbedPane` and the `JTable` in it to be with the full width of the `Jpanel` in which they are placed. Also I want to make my tabs to be just in one row. Is there any method which is used to set the layout of the tabs?
You can see the picture below.

[image]

That's the code which I'm using for the panel with the table:

```
public class GradesInfo extends JPanel {

    public GradesInfo () {
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 650;
        setPreferredSize(size);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Grades info"));

        // creating components
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        GradesTableModel tableModel = new GradesTableModel(new String[][] {{"Stephen", "6"}, {"Michael", "5"}});

        JTable table1 = new JTable();
        table1.setModel(tableModel);
        JTable table2 = new JTable();
        table2.setModel(tableModel);
        JTable table3 = new JTable();
        table3.setModel(tableModel);
        JTable table4 = new JTable();
        table4.setModel(tableModel);
        JTable table5 = new JTable();
        table5.setModel(tableModel);
        JTable table6 = new JTable();
        table6.setModel(tableModel);
        JTable table7 = new JTable();
        table7.setModel(tableModel);
        JTable table8 = new JTable();
        table8.setModel(tableModel);

        JScrollPane scr1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
        JScrollPane scr2 = new JScrollPane(table2);
        JScrollPane scr3 = new JScrollPane(table3);
        JScrollPane scr4 = new JScrollPane(table4);
        JScrollPane scr5 = new JScrollPane(table5);
        JScrollPane scr6 = new JScrollPane(table6);
        JScrollPane scr7 = new JScrollPane(table7);
        JScrollPane scr8 = new JScrollPane(table8);


        // adding the components
        tabbedPane.addTab("Semester 1", scr1);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Semester 2", scr2);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Semester 3", scr3);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Semester 4", scr4);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Semester 5", scr5);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Semester 6", scr6);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Semester 7", scr7);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Semester 8", scr8);

        add(tabbedPane);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the `JTabbedPane` or the `JScrollPane` or the `JTable`, the problem is with your `GradesInfo` `JPanel`.

`JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, which honours the `preferredSize` of the components added to it.

Instead, set the layout of the `GradesInfo` panel to `BorderLayout`

To change the way that the tabs are laid out, see [`JTabbedPane#setTabLayoutPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTabLayoutPolicy%28int%29)

You'll probably want yo use `JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT`

Comment: Yeah. That works. Thank you!

Do you have any idea how to make tabs in JTabbedPane to stay in one row?

Comment: @crypto Yep, check update, sorry, had to look it up ;)